# auth()->user() return null in ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel

i try to get the user id in ServiceProvider but auth()->user() return null after successfully login where is the problem ?

### It doesn't just work in test mode

```
public function boot()
    {
        dd(auth()->user()); // => return null
        try {
            Permission::get()->map(function ($permission) {
//                dd('$permission');
                Gate::define($permission->slug, function ($user) use ($permission) {
                    return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
                });
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            report($e);

}
```

Comment: the `boot` method in laravel serviceProvider is still in the process of booting the app. The app is not started yet. So it's null. what feature are you trying to archive?

Comment: I have a code I wrote for Role permissions that loads up through a ServiceProvider.

Comment: so why you need to use `auth()->user()` in  boot?

Comment: In test mode, even the permission model does not work, But it works well in postman

Comment: The idea, is that you do not need `auth()` in boot method. you can define `gate` in boot. That's all you need.

Comment: "where is the problem" Session has not started yet. Move that check/block into middleware.

Comment: In test mode (Phpunit), when I dd(Permission::all()) in serviceProvider , it gives the error "General error: 1 no such table: permissions." I don't know what to do. The access check is not done properly

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
use Auth;
public function boot(){
   Auth::user(); //or
   Auth::user()->name; //or
   Auth::user()->get();
}
```

Comment: return null  :((